# var/lib/jenkins/jobs/somejob/workspace/.venv/bin/python3 is used on pip install

Tags: pip

On my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine with python3 and pip 22/23 I have a strange situation where after doing an

```bash
pip install -U py-3rdparty-mediawiki
```

calling any of the scripts installed such as

```bash
wikibackup -h
```

leads to strange error messages as outlined in the feature request
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11816

The scripts are installed with

```bash
#!/hd/luxio/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/scan2wiki/workspace/.venv/bin/python3
```

as an interpreter - but that venv is from a nightly jenkins build and should not interfere with my main login

I  have no clue what causes this situation at this point and  the error message is not helpful at all.

I tried removing the venv directory and then get

```bash
wikibackup -h

-bash: /home/wf/.local/bin/wikibackup: /hd/luxio/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/scan2wiki/workspace/.venv/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

None of my environment variables points to scan2wiki

```bash
env | grep scan2wiki
```

```bash
pip list | grep py-3rdparty-mediawiki
py-3rdparty-mediawiki         0.9.0
```

**How can i debug/fix this to get a working**

```
pip install -U py-3rdparty-mediawiki
```

**again?**.

I only have the problem on a single machine - another Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine without the jenkins environment runs just fine.

Comment: Always use a form of `python -m pip` in order to make sure which Python interpreter is used. It often happens that `pip` is "linked" to a different Python interpreter than the one you actually want. Why it happens? This is hard to tell, some misconfiguration at some point. https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- But that is not a durable fix, if you want to really fix things you will have to investigate your own setup on your own machine and it is near impossible for us to help you with that.

Comment: @sinoroc thank you for the answer - in fact afert removing the bad venv environment and doing a reinstall of a new library version the error went away. The annoying part was just the unincomprehensible stack trace.